# "I saw him run" -- Why doesn't this require the past tense of "run"?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense

In a sentence like, "I saw him run," what is the rule that explains why "run" is in the present tense when "saw" is in the past tense? A similar construction, "She said he swam," requires past tense for both. I suspect the pronoun is governing verb tense. Is there a term for this?

Comment: But you would say "_She saw him swim_" not "_She saw him swam_"

Comment: "run" in your example is not in the present tense; it is the infinitive form.